# Minecraft 1.7.10 launcher won't launch mac osx maverix

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My minecraft lagged so i put the java in the trash and i restarted my macbook pro
after that I got it out the trash and didn't know where to place the file. When later i just put it in the minecraft folder. and i launched minecraft but it did not work so i deleted everything what has to do with minecraft on my mac even the minecraft folder at application support. I re-downloaded minecraft from the website. and it did not start. then I downloaded the newest java and it did not work. does anyone know. what to do because I bought the game and now I can't play.

Answer (score 3):

Please uninstall your current java, which includes removing ALL files related to it, such as the part that you put in your Minecraft folder (Which you weren't supposed to do, as it probably messed up the path).
Then install java again from [the Java website](http://java.com/inc/BrowserRedirect1.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling your Java. If that doesn't work, then try removing all things related to Java SE Binary and Java. Then reinstall Java.